# Streaming Amazon Instant Video in HD

Tags: streaming, amazon-video

Is it possible to watch **HD** Amazon Instant Video (eg, Amazon Prime) on non-Kindle Android devices? (Galaxy Nexus with MHL adapter)

AFAIK, Amazon does not support HD streaming in the browser; this would require a native app.

Google Play does support this, but I haven't been able to find anything about Amazon.  (other than Flash streaming, which I don't think will do HD)

Answer (score 1):

Just did it today on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

To stream Amazon Prime (or other Flash) movies:

1. Download Flash 11 onto your android device. You won't find it in the app market (Google pulled it this summer) but there are a couple different guides online. [I used this one from CNET.](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57554629-285/install-adobe-flash-player-on-jelly-bean-devices/)
2. Download the Dolphin browser from the app market (other browsers MAY work as well if they let you change the user agent string, but Dolphin makes it easy and is the only one I tested successfully on).
3. Go into the Dolphin browser settings and set the "User Agent" setting to "desktop".
4. Login to Amazon and you can now stream Amazon prime/instant movies.

I used an MHL adapter to output the video/audio to my receiver and can now watch the movies on my surround-sound projector setup (though its not surround sound).

YMMV, as I'm not sure if this works on all android devices but it works on my S3. Good luck!

Comment: This does not support HD.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Well in that case, the answer to your question is not yet.

Comment: It doesn't support HD, but it's the closest solution that I can find so far. I don't think his answer deserved a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and working today 08/01/2013. Tested on Asus TF700T and it looks beautiful.**

1. Side load Flash from DevHost: http://d-h.st/x4v
2. Tell browser to "Request Desktop Site" (Change Agent)
3. Sign in to Amazon and navigate to Prime
4. Play

CAVEAT: Remember to disable sleep time (Tablet will turn display off as if idle, so disable Idle times) and auto brightness.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is essentially the same advice as the other two answers, and I'm pretty sure it has the same issue. Although using Flash will allow you to view video, it does not allow you to view the HD video that the OP is specifically looking for.

Comment: More important caveat: No HD.

Answer (score 0):

FlashFox is working for me.  Only watched a couple videos so far. Not sure if in HD, but looks native on my 2nd gen Nexus 7 (1080).

Answer (score -1):

This worked until April 17th, 2013. Amazon changed something and Instant Video no longer works with even the latest versions of Flash for Android which can be downloaded from the Adobe Archive and side loaded.

The only option for viewing Amazon Instant Video that I have found is to download [Puffin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudmosa.puffinFree). It decodes the Flash video on their cloud Servers and streams it to the browser on your device in some other format. Sadly, it is a little herkyjerky and the audio is sometimes out of sync and full screen is more or less broken, although you can zoom in to fill the screen.

Comment: As with [the other answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/36119/981) that mentions using a browser (when it still worked), I don't think this supports HD playback that the OP is looking for. It doesn't on other devices (e.g. PCs).